# Writing a file by taking input from user only saves value for "x" only

Tags: c, file-io, fwrite

I'm implementing **Lagrange Interpolation to calculate square root of "y"**.Taking input from user and writing it to a file *"xyz.dat"* (binary) in order to plot/display the graphs using Matlab.

Values are calculated correctly but the file written do not have both the values for *x* and *y* when graph is displayed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    float x[100],y[100],a,s=1,t=1,k=0;

    int n,i,j,d=1;

    printf("\n\n Enter the number of the terms of the table: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\n\n Enter the respective values of the variables x and y: \n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        scanf ("%f",&x[i]);
        scanf("%f",&y[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n The table you entered is as follows :\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%0.3f\t%0.3f",x[i],y[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    while(d==1)
    {
        printf(" \n\n\n Enter the value of the x to find the respective value of y\n\n\n");
        scanf("%f",&a);
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            s=1;
            t=1;
            for(j=0; j<n; j++)
            {
                if(j!=i)
                {
                    s=s*(a-x[j]);
                    t=t*(x[i]-x[j]);
                }
            }
            k=k+((s/t)*y[i]);
        }
        printf("\n\n The respective value of the variable y is: %f",k);

        FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen("xyz.dat", "wb");
        fwrite((char *)x, sizeof(double), 1, fp);
        fclose(fp);

        printf("\n\n Do you want to continue?\n\n Press 1 to continue and any other key to exit");
        scanf("%d",&d);
    }
}
```

The Expected output should be stored in the file "xyz.dat" but when I plot the graph in Matlab it shows just some random values and only for "X" not for "Y"

Comment: this looks like `c`, did you tag it wrong? (the only c++ part is `#include<fstream>` and not used at all)

Answer (score 2):

Where are you writing the value of y? I can see that you write the value of *x* to the file

```
 fwrite((char *)x, sizeof(double), 1, fp);
```

Edit:
Example to correctly write integer to binary file
[fwrite() not working to write integer in binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565659/fwrite-not-working-to-write-integer-in-binary-file)

Comment: even the value of x is not written exactly as entered, and can you please tell how to write the value of Y?

Comment: @UmairAssad this post here answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565659/fwrite-not-working-to-write-integer-in-binary-file

Comment: @Swordfish sorry I don't have the rights to post comment right now

Answer (score 1):

```
fwrite((char *)y, sizeof(double), 1, fp);
```

This was needed to write the value for y, sorry for the wrong Tag!